# How to smoothly upgrade the targetFramework for a NuGet package

Tags: .net, nuget, target-framework

I have a NuGet package which currently targets .NET 4.5. The next version will instead target .NET 4.5.2. I have no interest in supporting both framework versions (these packages are only consumed internally), but I do want to make it obvious to consumers that they need to target 4.5.2. Right now, it seems that NuGet will allow a 4.5 project to install my package but it will be a no-op (since there are no DLLs to install for net45).

My question is, what can I do to improve this experience? Ideally I'd like to have the install fail when the targetFramework is wrong. Barring that, I'd settle for something like an error message.

Comment: Did you try adding the assembly into a lib\net452 directory so it only installs into a project that target NET 4.5.2?

Comment: @MattWard that's what it does by default. However, when I install that package in a 4.5 project it doesn't complain; it just silently no-ops.

Comment: That sounds like a nuget bug. I wouldn't expect nuget to allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to make sure that everything in your package is targeted at the new version. Then, NuGet will fail the install with this message:

> Could not install package 'XXX'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets  '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but
>   the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
>   that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
>   contact the package author

My problem was that even thought my DLL targeted net452, I had other elements in my nuspec file (e. g. content files) that still targeted net45. NuGet interprets this as my package being multi-targeted, and thus allows the install to proceed in a .NET 4.5 project (silently skipping the step of adding the DLL reference).